# What's the NSE of nmap?

Tags: nmap

When I use `nmap` for scanning IP, there prints logs:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-05 10:27 ?D1ú±ê×?ê±??

NSE: Loaded 148 scripts for scanning.

NSE: Script Pre-scanning.

Initiating NSE at 10:27

Completed NSE at 10:27, 0.00s elapsed

Initiating NSE at 10:27

Completed NSE at 10:27, 0.00s elapsed

Initiating Ping Scan at 10:27

Scanning 103.23.43.1 [4 ports]

Completed Ping Scan at 10:27, 1.12s elapsed (1 total hosts)

Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:27

Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:27, 1.31s elapsed

Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 10:27
```

there are many `NSE` in there, what't the meaning of it?

Comment: Learn more https://nmap.org/book/nse.html.

Answer (score 2):

The `NSE` mean `Nmap Scripting Engine`, you can understand this is `nmap` software's kernel, this implemented the namp's primary function.

NSE is part of namp and it also allows users to write (or share) scripts to automate a wide variety of networking tasks.

Comment: I am surprised how they did a scripting engine that does not slow down anything notably.

Answer (score 0):

if you navigate to

```
cd /usr/share/nmap/scripts
```

you will see bunch of preinstalled scripts in Kali Linux. this is how you use them with nmap.

```
nmap --scripts=ssh.brute.nse TargetIpAdress
```

in the same directory if you type

```
nano ssh-brute.nse
```

you will access to script to change the some options.

you can also download nse scripts from github. here are the 2 of them.

```
git clone https://github.com/scipag/vulscan
git clone https://github.com/vulnersCom/nmap-vulners
```

implementation of those scripts are slightly different. in the directory of those scripts

```
nmap --script vulscan targetIpAddress
```